# postgres && - Array Overlap operator with wildcard

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, wildcard

In postgres

```
select array['some', 'word'] && array ['some','xxx']   -- return true
select array['some', 'word'] && array ['','word']   -- return true
```

I'd like to know how I can use % wildcar in combination with && operator.

```
select array['some%', 'word'] && array ['','some']  -- I was thinking this will return true but it doesn't.
```

I want to check if a text array contains at least one element of another text array. The first text array can contains wildcard. What's the best way to  do that ?

Comment: My advice is not to use arrays or JSON in that case.

Comment: I'm using a jsonb field containing text array . 
@Laurenz Albe, what's the problem with array or json in this case?

Comment: The problem is that you will end up with a complicated query that won't perform well and cannot be indexed. If you store the data in regular columns, all that would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html) to parse every element of both arrays and compare them using `LIKE` or `ILIKE`:

```
SELECT EXISTS(
  SELECT  
  FROM unnest(array['some%', 'word']) i (txt),
       unnest(array ['','some']) j (txt)
  WHERE j.txt LIKE i.txt) AS overlaps;

 overlaps 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

If you want to apply the `%` to **all array elements**, just place it directly in the `WHERE` clause in the `LIKE` or `ILIKE` operator:

```
SELECT EXISTS(
  SELECT  
  FROM unnest(array['some', 'word']) i (txt),
       unnest(array ['','XXsomeXX']) j (txt)
  WHERE j.txt LIKE '%'||i.txt||'%') AS overlaps;

 overlaps 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6977392c19e243c165db589875ea5485)

Comment: suppose one of my array is jsonb field property, what kind of index may I use to  get query planer make index scan? 

    `SELECT EXISTS(
      SELECT  
      FROM unnest(ARRAY(  select * from  jsonb_array_elements_text(input->'listAddressOrigRef'))::text[]) i (txt),
           unnest(array ['','some']) j (txt)
      WHERE j.txt LIKE i.txt) AS overlaps;`

Comment: @soung you'd need to tell postgres where to get the values to index, see this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167965/144842